# What's the response to あなたにもっと早くしてなんて言われる覚えはないですよ。?

Tags: translation, meaning, jlpt, conversations

I found this conversation from a JLPT listening section. Here goes the question.

> あなたにもっと早くしてなんて言われる覚えはないですよ。

There are 3 choices. Pick one that is the proper response.

> １ すみません。失言でした。
>
> ２ そうですか。今度は覚えてくださいよ。
>
> ３ ええ、私もそのこと、忘れていました。

The site I found this test said that the correct answer is 1 without any explanation. However, I am confused why the answer is number 1 not 2.

I translated the first sentence as, "I don't remember that you told me to hurry." So I thought that the proper response is "You should remember that from now on".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is how 言われる覚え is not 言われた… but 言われ**る**, in other words, it doesn't mean if s/he was told or not. The verb form not being た but る means that the thing has not happened yet but is going to happen or should happen.

It's not reasonable to interpret this 覚え as memory either. You probably knew that the primary meaning of 覚える, which is cognate with 思う, is to feel rather than to memorize, but you might want to check it again. It's synonymous to [心当たり](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%BF%83%E5%BD%93%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A) here.

Anyway, what it means is that the speaker doesn't find it reasonable to be told so. Given that, you can judge that #2 and #3 are not a contender.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also can I use it like this. Can a mom said to a child sth like 2時までゲーム遊んでも大丈夫って言った覚えはないよ to her child who doesn't sleep.

Comment: Yes, and you can interpret it as memory when it's combined with a past form.