# What meaning does 覚え have in ～る覚えはない?

Tags: translation, definitions

In a novel, this character speaking feels as if she's been betrayed by someone. The protagonist then tries to calm her down by coming up with a possible reason for why the person who betrayed her might've done what they did. She then says:

> ……あら。あなた、私を言いくるめようっていうの？それとも、同情しているのかしら？私ね、見ず知らずの人に同情される覚えはないの

How should 覚えはない be translated here?

An answer to [a similar question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60822/whats-the-response-to-%E3%81%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E6%97%A9%E3%81%8F%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6%E8%A8%80%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E8%A6%9A%E3%81%88%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%82%88?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top) states that the 覚え here, given that a verb in its non-past form precedes it, should not be interpreted as memory, but rather as a synonym of 心当たり. Would it be correct then to interpret the sentence as "I don't happen to know of any stranger that pities (has pitied?) me, (so it is ridiculous for a stranger like you to pity me)."?

If so, does interpreting 覚え as "memory" make sense too? "I have no recollection of being pitied by a stranger, (so you, a stranger, should not pity me either)."

Furthermore, the answer also says "The verb form not being た but る means that the thing has not happened yet but is going to happen or should happen. ", which doesn't seem to make sense here either, as the protagonist has already performed the action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically a duplicate of the linked question, but supplementing the answer, *present tense* + 覚えはない is used in "it's none of your business"/"stepping over the line" situation. To an extent, it's a way to express *you are being presumptuous by doing (the verb)*.

An interchangeable expression is *present tense* + 筋合いはない. 筋合い means *reason* in a broad sense, and 筋合いはない literally means *there's no reason (for you to do that)*.

同情される覚えはない essentially means *your pity annoys me*.

For other examples:

- 命令される覚えはない ~ you are being bossy (and you are not in a position to be so to me).
- こんなことをしてもらう覚えはない ~ you are doing too much for me (usually about a favor which makes the speaker uncomfortable).